# i cannot save data in binary mode with c++

Tags: c++, binaryfiles

I want to write in a binary file but when I open it I can read what is there. Is this natural? I know that binary files can only be interpretted by computers. I am confused, please help.
Here is my code:

```
Product p;
create(p);
        std::ofstream myfile("example.bin",std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
        myfile << p;
        myfile.close();

friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream &is, Product& prod);
    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream &os, const Product& prod);
```

Comment: In short, use [`ofstream::write(...)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) (or `put()` for one byte)

Comment: how are you overriding your << operator for Product ?!

Comment: There is no magic. what ever the << operator of Product gives, that is what gets written. "Binary file" means, it can contain "anything", including plain text, while "text file" just means it will contain only printable characters of whatever encoding is used in the file.

Comment: How are people meant to know why `Product.operator <<` does what it does, when you didn't show what it does...? Please, post complete code or don't post.

Comment: All files contain binary data. Of the major platforms "text mode" only makes a difference on Windows, and even then only regarding the interpretation of newlines (when writing). If you use formatted output, your file will contain normal character sequences regardless of opening mode.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put operator overloading here, i fix it, is it something wrong with that?

Comment: @MareșȘtefan Your declarations aren't interesting (if they are correct, they all look the same). The definitions could be, but `<<` and `>>` operators are for writing formatted data (i.e. text).

Answer (score 3):

You should not use `<<` operator with binary files, it is intended to be used with text files.

You should use the [`write(...)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/write/) method of ostream.

In your case:

```
Product p;
create(p);
std::ofstream myfile("example.bin", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
myfile.write(&p, sizeof(p));
myfile.close();
```

Comment: Note that this is only valid code if `Product` is a trivially copyable type. Or well, *writing* is "legal" of course, but you can't ever read it back if it isn't. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/TriviallyCopyable

Comment: And in addition to being trivial, it better not contain pointers -- these don't accomodate well to being loaded in a foreign address space.

Answer (score 0):

to write into a binary file, you need to use write,

write (const char* s, streamsize n);

use reinterprete_cast for the pointer, and pass the size of your object to it.

if it is a pod (test with std::is_pod_v<>), you could do with

```
myfile.write(reinterpret_cas<const char *>(&p), sizeof(p))
```

otherwise, you have to serialize your object using a serializer like boost serializer